# Is omitting a repeated subject and predicate in attributive clauses ok?

Tags: grammaticality, clauses, subordinate-clauses

Can I omit the conjunction, the subject, and the auxiliary verb in this attributive clause in (1)

1. I had returned the book **(which I had)** borrowed from library.

to produce (2):

2. I had returned the book borrowed from library.

And for clauses in the passive mode like (3):

3. I had returned the book **(which had)** been borrowed from library.

Can I omit the parenthesized part of (3) to produce this version (4)?

4. I had returned the book been borrowed from library.

Comment: You're not deleting "which I had". You're deleting _which was_. The rule ([Whiz-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121619/15299)) deletes a relative pronoun subject and an auxiliary form of _be_ (in this case for the passive) and leaves the rest.

Comment: We know books are _borrowed_ from libraries. Saying "I had returned the library book" is enough.

Comment: @JohnLawler explains why sentence 2 is acceptable. Sentence 4 is ungrammatical because the past participle "been" lacks a parent. (The auxiliary verb "had" can not be its parent because its subject is "I", which is surely not the subject of "had been borrowed".)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I would advise against using the term 'parent'. It's only meaningful to linguists in certain theoretical grammars, and quite out of place on ELL where answers should be based on straightforward traditional descriptive grammar.

Comment: What do you mean by 'OK'? Using << I had returned the book borrowed from the library.  >>as a replacement for << I had returned the book  which I had  borrowed from the library. >> certainly gives another grammatical sentence, but information is lost. The two sentences are grammatical but quite a distance from being from synonymous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I only meant grammatically acceptable. I agree that some information is lost.

Comment: Deletion rules always lose information. In this case the tense of _be_ got lost, but from context we can figure out that it must be in the past.

Comment: @John Lawler
So is the sentence 1 ungrammatical? Or just don't recommend the expression by past perfect tense? In fact I also want to know how should I reduce clauses for any tenses (like the present/past perfect, or present/past perfect continuous).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth 
In my opinion, the reduced sentence is simpler and tidier than original, so I wish for a general rule for any clauses of any tenses. If the equivalent content (include auxiliary verbs) always can be omitted in clause, by this rule, the lost subject, tense or other information can be deduced clearly -- if something is lost, we can find it out in the main clause.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Does the "parent" means subject?

Comment: @HEAP No. When two words are directly related (syntactically), we can identify one as parent and the other as child. If a word is an orphan, then the parts of the sentence aren't properly connected. (With a few exceptions.)

Comment: As an English teacher, I would not knock off a mark for ungrammaticality in the sentence 'I had returned the book borrowed from **the** library'. However, I _would_ deduct a mark if someone claimed that 'I had returned the book borrowed from the library' was exactly synonymous with 'I had returned the book which I had borrowed from library'. Detail is lost. // On the other hand, 'I had returned the book which had been borrowed from the library'  → 'I had returned the book borrowed from the library' loses no significant detail.

Comment: Thx @MarcInManhattan, that sounds complex but valid!

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Thank you teacher, maybe there are no rules which I want, but I guess I have gotten the point!

Comment: I seem to have missed out somewhere in the previous comment that I was employed as a maths/science teacher. The 'As an English' teacher was/is irrealis and needed this disclaimer, which I apologise for omitting. _But I did the occasional supply lesson in English_.